# Windows Server 2012 does not see internal RDX drive, but it shows in the BIOS

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, windows-server

We’re running `Windows Server Essentials 2012` on a new HP Proliant Server, and we bought both an internal and USB 3.0 external RDX drive with a few 500GB RDX cartridges. We are running into two problems and I was hoping anyone had some help.

1) **Windows Server 2012 does not see the internal RDX drive.** We’ve booted with and without a cartridge in. BIOS sees the drive but Windows doesn't. By swapping around cables and ports, we've ruled out the motherboard, ports and cables as being the problem.

2) **The USB RDX drive is not recognized as an available backup destination by the built in backup application in Windows Server 2012.** The USB drive is detected in windows however, and works in every other way.

We want to use the windows built in backup application to preform back-ups but both of the above two problems put us in like a catch-22 (I think it's a catch-22..., whatever it is, it is cruel).

Thank you for reading and your help.

EDIT: Also, we are talking with Tandberg Data, the manufacturer, but they have have slow with the help, it looks like they are merging with another company right now (tandbergdata.com)

EDIT: After doing some more research I have come to the conclusion that #2 is not possible. There are some obscure workarounds but windows does not want to accept a removable drive as a backup device (since the RDX drives can be ejected mid-backup).

Sources:
http://www.sbsfaq.com/?p=2754

Comment: When trying to use the USB drive in Windows Server Backup, what kind of backup are you attempting?  And does that drive/cartridge already contain a partition and have a drive letter assigned to it? for the internal drive, it sounds like it may just be busted (the receiver, not the cartridges/drives). Take it out and try it in another computer (perhaps one running a different, known-compatible OS); if it doesn't work there either, then I'd suspect the RDX receiver is DOA.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, We are attempting a scheduled backup that will auto-run. Unfortunately, per my edit above, I have found that it is just not possible. See second edit.